# JavaScript smooth content slider

Tags: javascript

So, I'm working on a project where I need a content slider to be smooth and I can't find a way to do it. I need a smooth transition between `div` elements and code so that when I'm in a `div` it appears on the little balls above. I'm pretty new at `javascript` there must be a ton of things that are wrong but I really need help.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 2200px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#itemOne {
    background-color: #ADFF2F;
}
#itemTwo {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
}
#itemThree {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
#itemFour {
    background-color: #DC143C;
}
#contentContainer {
 margin-left: 20px;  
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.caixa {
 width: 600px;
 height: 360px;
}
.seta1 {
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 170px;
 float:left;
}
.seta2 {
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 170px;
 float:right;
}
.butao {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 5px;
 height: 16px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 border: solid black 2px;
 margin-left: 6px;
}
.butao:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}
.navegacao{
 margin-left: 245px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 40px;
}
#textoesquerda {
 float:left;
 width: 260px;
 height: 330px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: black;
}
#textodireita {
 float: right;
    width: 260px;
 height: 330px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: pink;
}
.mySlides {
 display:none
}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {
 cursor:pointer
}
.w3-badge {
 height:13px;
 width:13px;
 padding:0;
 border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<title>An Interesting Title Goes Here</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
 

</style>

<body>
<div class="caixa">
<div class="seta1" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
<div class="seta2" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
 <div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="itemOne" class="content">
      <div id="textoesquerda">
       <p>
        
       </p>
      </div>
      <div id="textodireita">
       <p>
        
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="itemTwo" class="content"></div>
     <div id="itemThree" class="content"></div>
     <div id="itemFour" class="content"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="navegacao">
  <button class="butao" id="butao1" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao2" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao3" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao4" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></button>
 </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("itemLinks");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than posting your entire program, please consider posting just a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable piece of the part of it that you're having trouble with. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if I wanted to post the entire code i had posted the whole website, but no, in this case I separate the slider code to just post this piece of code here and not the entire website ;)

Comment: That looks to me like a lot more than just the code for a slider. There seem to be unrelated CSS declarations and markup in there. You may want to consider paring it down more next time you ask a question to make it easier for people to read it and answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer:

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 2200px;
    position:relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out; //changes made
    left:0;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#itemOne {
    background-color: #ADFF2F;
}
#itemTwo {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
}
#itemThree {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
#itemFour {
    background-color: #DC143C;
}
#contentContainer {
    margin-left: 20px;  
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.caixa {
    width: 600px;
    height: 360px;
}
.seta1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 170px;
    float:left;
}
.seta2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 170px;
    float:right;
}
.butao {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 5px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: solid black 2px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.butao:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
.navegacao{
    margin-left: 245px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}
#textoesquerda {
    float:left;
    width: 260px;
    height: 330px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
#textodireita {
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
    height: 330px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.mySlides {
    display:none
}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {
    cursor:pointer
}
.w3-badge {
    height:13px;
    width:13px;
    padding:0;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

**HTML/JS :**

```
<head>
<title>An Interesting Title Goes Here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>


</style>

<body>
<div class="caixa">
<div class="seta1" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
<div class="seta2" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
 <div id="contentContainer">
     <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itemOne" class="content">
            <div id="textoesquerda">
                <p>
                    1
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="textodireita">
                <p>
                    1
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="itemTwo" class="content">2</div>
        <div id="itemThree" class="content">3</div>
        <div id="itemFour" class="content">4</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="navegacao">
    <button class="butao" id="butao1" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao2" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao3" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao4" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></button>
 </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var y = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("butao");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }

  //changes made
  y.style.left = '-' + ((slideIndex-1)*x[slideIndex-1].offsetWidth) + "px";

  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you could take inspiration from this bootstrap theme https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

or from http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of show/hide the content, you have to move the `wrapper` div with respect to `slideIndex`. I made the wrapper div to `position:relative` and setting the left position with respect to slideIndex via javascript. And the smooth animation is handled by CSS transition.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 2200px;
    position:relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out; //changes made
    left:0;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#itemOne {
    background-color: #ADFF2F;
}
#itemTwo {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
}
#itemThree {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
#itemFour {
    background-color: #DC143C;
}
#contentContainer {
 margin-left: 20px;  
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.caixa {
 width: 600px;
 height: 360px;
}
.seta1 {
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 170px;
 float:left;
}
.seta2 {
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 170px;
 float:right;
}
.butao {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 5px;
 height: 16px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 border: solid black 2px;
 margin-left: 6px;
}
.butao:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}
.navegacao{
 margin-left: 245px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 40px;
}
#textoesquerda {
 float:left;
 width: 260px;
 height: 330px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: black;
}
#textodireita {
 float: right;
    width: 260px;
 height: 330px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: pink;
}
.mySlides {
 display:none
}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {
 cursor:pointer
}
.w3-badge {
 height:13px;
 width:13px;
 padding:0;
 border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<title>An Interesting Title Goes Here</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
 

</style>

<body>
<div class="caixa">
<div class="seta1" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
<div class="seta2" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
 <div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="itemOne" class="content">
      <div id="textoesquerda">
       <p>
        1
       </p>
      </div>
      <div id="textodireita">
       <p>
        1
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="itemTwo" class="content">2</div>
     <div id="itemThree" class="content">3</div>
     <div id="itemFour" class="content">4</div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="navegacao">
  <button class="butao" id="butao1" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao2" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao3" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></button>
    <button class="butao" id="butao4" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></button>
 </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var y = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("butao");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }

  //changes made
  y.style.left = '-' + ((slideIndex-1)*x[slideIndex-1].offsetWidth) + "px";
    
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code does the smooth transition but it doesnt worl like it is supose too, it hides the first div and never shower her. whats the problem?

Comment: @JoãoMonteiro upadted the code - used `slideIndex` instead of `(slideIndex-1)` since the `slideIndex` value always start with `1`, but the first element index is `0` when using in code. Check now

Comment: can u reload the page and try again. I can see all 4 slides animating.

Comment: u can see the first one? a yellow one with div inside??

Comment: yes first slide with two divs (black and pale red). And I placed number inside the divs to identify